# Аннотация @NotNull и аннотация @NotBlank

Tags: java, аннотации

Вопрос по поводу сообшений, которые пишут в аннотациях.

При инициализации пустой строкой переменную как в моём случае, должен ли я получить вывод сообшения в консоль ? Где я должен увидеть вывод данного сообшения ?

```
@NotBlank (message = "First name can't be an empty field")
@NotNull(message = "First name can't be an empty field")
private static String name;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    init("");
}

public static void init(String value){

    name = value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная аннотация является частью спецификации [Java Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/). Для того чтобы увидеть эти сообщения, нужно пропустить невалидный объект через валидатор. В случае с контейнером(web-сервером) данный валидатор может вызываться прозрачно. Вот пример функции, которая валидирует переданный объект и бросает исключение, если тот не валиден

```
public static <T extends Object> void  validate( T object ) throws RuntimeException{
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> valRes = validator.validate( object );
    if( ! valRes.isEmpty() ){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Validation failed for: ");
        sb.append(object);

        for( ConstraintViolation<T> fail : valRes) {
            sb.append("\n      ").append( fail.getPropertyPath() ).append(" ").append( fail.getMessage() );
        }
        throw new RuntimeException( sb.toString() );
    }
}
```

В качестве класса для типа `T` можно использовать какой-либо класс у которого поля помечены, к примеру, аннотацией `@NotNull`.

P.S. вообще данные аннотации не стоит устанавливать на статические поля.

Comment: Скажи мне что происходит в случае с веб сервисом и валидацией ? При написании веб сервиса я так понимаю того кода который ты написал сверху не нужно, так как контенер вызывает этот валидатор самостоятельно ? Не могу понять сам процесс валидации при наличии веб сервиса и запросов на этот веб сервис ? 
Где он запускается и кто за него ответственен, каким образом выводятся сообшения в аннотациях при не правильной валидации ?

Comment: @maks.burkov примерно так и есть. При построении веб-сервиса контейнер изучает сигнатуры методов на предмет наличия аргументов, у которых имеются соответствующие аннотации. Соответственно перед вызовом самого метода аргументы сначала отдаются в валидатор, и если тот находит несоответствия, то вместо вызова конечной функции вызывается обработчик таких ошибок. Вообще это тема довольно обширна, поэтому сначала поизучай документацию, а потом задавай дополнительные вопросы.